# Return of the path of ":/filename" in pyqt function QIcon

Tags: python, pyqt

I try to understand the code of someone else and he is using the `QIcon` function to set the WindowIcon. As I used the `QIcon` before, I used an absolute path inside my programm like this:

```py
...
app = QApplication([])
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon('.\\MyApp\\data\\Logo.png'))
    start_window = StartWindow()
    start_window.show()
    app.exit(app.exec_())
...
```

In his Code he uses a utility function to call `QIcon` to be able to change the filename. But instead of an absolute path he is calling `QIcon(':/' + filename)`.

I am not able to achieve the same results with this "relative" path. I might get anything else wrong or misunderstand the use of `:/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prefix ":/" is a virtual path that only recognizes the elements of Qt since it is based on The [Qt Resource System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html), in C++ what it does is to embed the resource (images, files or any type of static file) in the binary . In python that idea is also extrapolated generating a .py using the resources as a source.

In C++ the rcc tool is used and in PyQt5 pyrcc5 is used (in PyQt4 pyrcc4 is used), in PySide2 you can use pyside2-rcc or rcc.

The steps to use it are simple:

1. create a .qrc, you can do that with Qt Designer (check the menu View-> Resource Browser), although the format is a simple xml.

**myresource.qrc**

````
```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>Logo.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```
````

2. You convert it to .py using pyrcc5 (or the other tools):

   ```
   pyrcc5 myresource.qrc -o myresource_rc.py
   ```
3. Then you import it into the file where you are going to use it:

   **main.py**

   ```
   # ...
   import myresource_rc
   # ...
   ```
4. Use it:

   ```
   app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(':/Logo.png'))
   ```

See [The PyQt5 Resource System](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/resources.html)